# IP Subnet Notation

Tags: ip-address, notation, subnet

On a lab to regarding network topology using port scanners, I am instructed "to develop a network inventory and topology for the 123.218.44.0/24 subnet."

What does the notation 0/24 mean there? I had assumed it meant to consider the network range 123.218.44.0 to 123.218.44.24. When I use nmap against a range, using parameters in this format:

```
nmap -sS -O 123.218.44.0/24
```

nmap reports that it scanned 256 hosts, presumably 123.218.44.0 to 123.218.44.255. There is only one host between 0 and 24, but there are 4 hosts between 101 and 255. I assume that I am meant to find all 5 of those hosts, but I don't understand the notation so I'm not sure. Can anyone clarify for me?

Comment: Edit your question to say "I'm trying to write a simple socket-based server and running into trouble understanding how addresses work" and that way it won't get deleted. :)

Comment: Heh, is it downvoted and nominated for closed due to not being programming related? I don't quite understand. All this work is a precursor to programming in the course, surely it can be understood that this is prerequisite knowledge for sockets programming. No? I am confused.

Comment: I agree that I really don't see why this was closed down. The question might not be that well phrased, but for me it *is* related to network programming and therefore on-topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: This site is for specific, programming related questions and answers. You're asking a question about a specific network notation. That's not programming related. See Earwicker's comment :)

Comment: Even without that, the question most definitely is programming related. People are much too close-happly.

Comment: This is 100% programming related. Voting to reopen

Comment: More detailed answers can be found on the [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/the-slash-after-an-ip-address-cidr-notation).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

That's [Classless Inter-Doman Routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation) notation. The /24 means that the routing prefix of the subnet is 24 bits long, which means there's ony 8 bits left for the subnet itself, i.e. 123.218.44.0 to 123.218.44.255

Comment: And is 123.218.44 basically the same as 123.218.44.0/24 when it comes to things like Apache ip location restrictions?

Comment: @chrismarx No. 123.218.44.0/24 would match ips in the range of 123.218.44.0 through 123.218.44.255

Answer (score 8):

/24 means the mask is 255.255.255.0

And the other posters are correct about /24 being CIDR.

Answer (score 6):

The "0/24" is [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation).  It's a standard way to represent the [subnet mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Subnet_Mask#Binary_subnet_masks).

Answer (score 1):

/24 represents 255.255.255.0 which is the default subnet mask of Class C ip address which has a number of 16777216 subnets and 254 hosts